# Docker's `docker0` device dies repeatedly (`inet addr` disappears)

Tags: networking, docker, containers, connectivity

I'm running `Docker version 1.4.1, build 5bc2ff8` on Ubuntu 14.04. When I `docker run` any container, after a few minutes my `docker0` bridge "dies", and the container stops being able to reach the network. Before the connection dies, running `ifconfig` reports a `docker0` device with an `inet addr` like:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:84:7a:fe:97:99  
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          [... etc.]
```

But after the connection dies, `ifconfig` shows that the ipv4 address has gone away:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 56:84:7a:fe:97:99 
          inet6 addr: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8116 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15995 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2444859 (2.4 MB)  TX bytes:17440729 (17.4 MB)
```

Restarting docker, e.g. with `sudo service docker restart`, brings the device back up -- but all my containers die and the problem starts over again. I can't reliably get anything to run for more than a few minutes at a time. Not long enough to even complete a `docker build` for most projects.

1. What could be causing this?
2. How can I diagnose it?
3. What are some possible solutions?

Thanks!

---

Update: I can reliably trigger this `docker0`-dropping behavior simply by starting a container with `docker run -t -i ubuntu /bin/bash`, and then exiting with `ctrl-d`. When I do so, here's what I see in `/var/log/syslog`

```
myhost kernel:  docker0: port 1(veth80ddeaf) entered disabled state
myhost kernel:  device veth80ddeaf left promiscuous mode
myhost kernel:  docker0: port 1(veth80ddeaf) entered disabled state
'

myhost dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
myhost dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
myhost dhclient: All rights reserved.
myhost dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
myhost dhclient: 
myhost dhclient: Listening on LPF/docker0/56:84:7a:fe:97:99
myhost dhclient: Sending on   LPF/docker0/56:84:7a:fe:97:99
myhost dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
myhost kernel:  IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): docker0: link is not ready
```

---

Update #2: The frequency of failure seems to depend on how long the container runs. For example:

```
docker run -i -t  ubuntu   sleep 0
--> `docker0` "survives" ~100% of the time

docker run -i -t  ubuntu   sleep 1
--> `docker0` survives ~80% of the time

docker run -i -t  ubuntu   sleep 5
--> `docker0` survives ~0% of the time
```

Comment: Try to specify `--net="host"` as workaround. Will it works?

Comment: @maxd specifying `--net="host"` would prevent me from containerizing the container's networking. So that's not a solution to my problem -- thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 7):

I have had a similar problem: every time I restarted docker, `docker0` bridge went up, and then, as soon as I executed `docker run hello-world` and the program exited, it was gone. I could not get the hello-world to work again because `docker0` vanished.

So I checked the system log (syslog via `gnome-system-log`) from a PC where docker worked regularly and the PC I was having this problem, the logs from the hello world command were a bit different in order, but the same in essence. But here's something I noticed: on the problematic PC, docker was using `netscript` to handle network interfaces, as soon as I removed it through `sudo apt remove netscript-2.4` and restarted docker with `sudo systemctl restart docker`, everything went back to normal.

Comment: The only issue with your response that it is not very visible :D, solved my issue like a charm  !

Comment: I just upgraded from ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and some of my docker-compose services wouldn't come up and this was the fix. I originally dismissed this as a fix but I saw `Usage: netscript ifup|ifdown|ifqos|ifreload` in /var/log/syslog around the docker error and it seemed like compose or docker was trying to use netscript incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I diagnose it?

When `docker0` has an ip address, does it go away if you *don't* start any containers?  If it persists indefinitely until you start a container, I would start by looking at the Docker logs as well as tailing the system logs when you start a container.

Does the ip address disappear at set intervals (e.g., every N minutes)?  If so, I would look for logs from `cron` to see if some periodic task is responsible.

Are you running NetworkManager?  Does disabling NetworkManager make the problem go away?  I am running Docker on a system with NetworkManager without a problem, but I have `no-auto-default=*` set in my config, which may have an impact on this sort of thing.

**Update**

This is very suspicious:

```
myhost dhclient: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
myhost dhclient: Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
myhost dhclient: All rights reserved.
myhost dhclient: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
myhost dhclient: 
myhost dhclient: Listening on LPF/docker0/56:84:7a:fe:97:99
myhost dhclient: Sending on   LPF/docker0/56:84:7a:fe:97:99
myhost dhclient: Sending on   Socket/fallback
```

There should not be any `dhclient` process listening on `docker0`, and this is absolutely what is causing your ip address to disappear.  If you are not explicitly running a dhcp client on this interface, this really suggests that NetworkManager is in fact trying to manage this interface.  You said you disabled NetworkManager, but did you confirm that the process was stopped?  What is the parent process of the `dhclient` that is listening on `docker0`?  If you stop the `dhclient` process, does it get restarted?  Does the problem go away?

Comment: Thanks @larsks --great suggestions! I can report that the behavior 1) does not occur if I don't start *any* docker containers, 2) is not time-based, and 3) persists when `network-manager` is disabled. I've included a relevant `syslog` dump in an update to my question above. I'd appreciate any additional guidance.

Comment: See additional update suggesting a race condition (duration of container live appears to affect the probability of failure). Any further thoughts about how to debug?

Comment: When I run `ps aux | grep -i dhclient`  and `ps aux | grep -i network` on my host system, I can confirm there are no results (`dhclient` is not running). But I do see these `myhost dhclient` entries in syslog -- possibly `dhclient` is somehow being invoked because of the container's stop event? Is there some way I can investigate this possibility?

Comment: I'd love to get your take on this -- it appears that no `dhclient` is running on my host system before/after I start a new docker container. Is it possible that the launch of `dhclient` is somehow being triggered only when the container exits, or that some other process (called something other than `dhclient` is causing the `myhost dhclient` log lines to appear in my syslog)?

Comment: I got the same problem here (dhclient started right after docker container exit). I thought as well that NetworkManager was the problem. But the problem was in fact related to wicd (wired and wireless network manager) another network manager installed on my machine. Disabling wicd fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

The `wcid` service seems to be the cause indeed.
I found in the config :

> (/etc/wicd/manager-settings.conf):
>   wired_interface = docker0

I changed this to `eth0`.

I forgot to restart the service, but my issue disappeared when the `wicd` service was stopped.
After the change above I started it again I had no more issues with it.

Apparently some autoconfig issue with `wicd`?

To get the bridge working again, you can use:

```
sudo ip addr add 172.17.0.1/24 dev docker0
```

and the bridge will get the IP back.

Comment: I suspected from wicd then I uninstalled but problem persisted. Maybe service was still there because I edited this file and rebooted system and network is ok now.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue and the root cause was `wicd`. Running:

```
sudo service wicd stop
sudo service docker restart
```

...should do the trick.

Comment: you are an absolute life saver, spent 6 hours on this, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 22:
In short: `sudo apt remove netscript-2.4`

Yes, this solution is equivalent to the previous, but the previous is difficult to get the point.