# Docker on GCE always restarting

Tags: django, docker, nginx, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

Problems I am having with my Docker instance on a GCE VM:

1. It keeps restarting
2. I cannot access `tcp:80` after creating several firewall policies

Here are the steps I took in creating the instance with `gcloud`: [Why is Google Compute Engine not running my container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60965622/why-is-google-compute-engine-not-running-my-container)

What I have tried:

- To open the port, I created several Firewall policies and even tagged the VM, but still getting this when I run `nmap -Pn 34.XX.XXX.XXX`

```
PORT    STATE SERVICE
25/tcp  open  smtp
110/tcp open  pop3
119/tcp open  nntp
143/tcp open  imap
465/tcp open  smtps
563/tcp open  snews
587/tcp open  submission
993/tcp open  imaps
995/tcp open  pop3s

# 80/tcp is not open
```

Alternatively, I tried opening the port from inside the container after `SSH`:

```
docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/<project>/<repo>/<image:v2>

curl http://127.0.0.1

#which results in:
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused
```

- Also, running `docker ps` from within the container shows a `restarting` status.

If it helps, I have two `docker-compose` files, one local and prod. The prod has the following details:

```
version: '3'

services: 
  web:
    restart: on-failure
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    image: <image-name>
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles 
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles 
    expose:
      - 8000
    command: gunicorn core.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    env_file:
      - ./.env.dev
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    env_file:
      - ./.env.prod
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5432

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/home/app/web/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/home/app/web/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 1337:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  pgdata:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong at this point. I've killed many instances with different `restart-policies` but it stays the same. I have the sample setup running `nginx` successfully. It also works successfully locally.

- **Could I be using the wrong `compose` file?**
- **Is my project `nginx` settings wrong?**
- **Why is the container always restarting?**
- **Why can't I open `tcp:80` after setting Firewall rules**
- **Does tagging such as `:v2` after the performance on the container in GCE?**

I'd appreciate any help. I have wasted hours trying to figure it out.

PS: If it helps, the project is built with `Django` and `Python3.9`

Comment: Nothing you've shown includes port 80 as the first `ports:` number, so none of these containers would be listening on port 80.  Does this setup work in a local environment?  If one of the containers is restarting, have you looked at its logs?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks. Correct me if I'm wrong. I have `nginx` running on `port 1337:80`. The setup runs successfully in local env. I can access it on both 80 and 1337. I just checked the logs and I got 

`docker0: port 2(vethe7cf915) entered blocking state` 
`docker0: port 2(veth36af2d1) entered disabled state`

I'm definitely doing something wrong, I just don't know what.

Comment: Would you please run this command `systemctl stop wicd
systemctl restart docker` as per this  thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28923743/dockers-docker0-device-dies-repeatedly-inet-addr-disappears 
https://www.linode.com/community/questions/18169/coreos-docker0-interface-problems

Comment: @Mahboob I got `Failed to stop wicd.service: Access denied`. Restarted the docker daemon and issue stays the same.

Comment: Did you used `sudo` before the command?

Comment: Yes. I figured the restart issue from my nginx conf, that has been fixed but `port:80` remains closed.

Comment: What is the output of `curl -I 127.0.0.1`?